# Dictionary not returning the value thanks to a key in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am developing a function in vba to create and fill a dictionary.

Keys of the dictionary are the following :

```
CATEGORY 1
CATEGORY 2
```

When I try to retrieve the value with the following code, it's not working :

```
Dim test As String
test=mydico("CATEGORY 1")
```

The variable test is empty.

But what I don't understand and that's very strange is that with the following code :

```
For Each Key In mydico.Keys()
    Dim test As String
    test = categoriesDico(key)
Next
```

When the key is equal to "CATEGORY 1", test is filled with the appropriate value, I don't understand why as putting "CATEGORY 1" or putting a key (with the value "CATEGORY 1") is the same.

Comment: Could you show where you populate both `mydico` and `categoriesDico`

Comment: You might have a look over here: http://www.snb-vba.eu/VBA_Dictionary_en.html

Answer (score 4):

I know this is old, but in case anyone finds their way here like I did...
I had this problem (i.e. a var as key vs a manually entered string as key, in order to retrieve a value by key from a dictionary - one worked, the other didn't - other way round in my case)
I fixed it by using the CStr function, i.e. making sure that the key type as stored and the type I was using to retrieve a value by key from the dictionary were the same, i.e.

```
dict("key1") = "value1"
dict("key2") = "value2"
```

etc

and the key is of type string

if I look up "key1" like this:

```
result = dict("key1")
result shows as "value1"
```

now let's say I have

```
var="key1"
```

of type string/variant and I want to look it up in the dict and retrieve the corresponding value. if I do this:

```
result = dict(var)
result shows as blank
```

I have to do this

```
result = dict(CStr(var))
```

then I get the result back as "value1" as expected